# Join table Error in php mysql

Tags: php, sql

I have two tables, how could I join them on `employee_apply.emplr_ehid = employer_info.emplr_ehid`?

#### 1st Table: employee_apply

```
id      apply_date |     emp_uhid     | emplr_ehid  |   job_jhid
10|     2014-05-12 |    1386038162    | 1397939308  |   1388345552
11|     2014-05-12 |    1397941439    | 1397939308  |   1397936001
```

#### 2nd Table : employer_info

```
id | emplr_id | emplr_ehid | emplr_name
16 | 10001    | 1397939308 | ABCD..
```

Here is my query:

```
$query="SELECT employee_apply.emp_uhid, employee_apply.emplr_ehid, employer_info.emplr_name FROM employee_apply LEFT JOIN employee_apply employee_apply.emplr_ehid = employer_info.emplr_ehid";
```

Here is the error message:

> Error : mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in.

Comment: Where is your SQL query?

Comment: *"Join table Error in php mysql"* --- being?

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: **Don't say "I got an error". Always say "Here is the error I got" and then show us the exact error.** Don't paraphrase it. Don't retype it. Cut & paste the error message exactly from your screen.

Comment: So post it in your question then. That's what you should have done in the first place. (Edit: OP deleted comment with query content).

Comment: $query="SELECT employee_apply.emp_uhid, employee_apply.emplr_ehid, employer_info.emplr_name
FROM employee_apply  LEFT JOIN employee_apply employee_apply.emplr_ehid = employer_info.emplr_ehid";

Comment: ^--<<< **DO NOT DO THAT**

Comment: Error :  mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in.

Comment: Ok. I think you are having a hard time with posting code and I understand that. @user2730453 Edit: I removed both my -1 and my vote to close. Next time, do post code and error messages in your question and not the comments box as soon as you post your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM `employee_apply` 
LEFT JOIN `employer_info` 
ON `employee_apply`.`emplr_ehid` = `employer_info`.`emplr_ehid`;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want an inner join:

```
SELECT * FROM employee_apply 
INNER JOIN employer_info 
ON employee_apply.emplr_ehid = employer_info.emplr_ehid
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already performed the join in your question, but for illustration purposes here is the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `employee_apply`
JOIN `employer_info`
ON `employee_apply`.`emplr_ehid` = `employer_info`.`emplr_ehid`;
```